# authentication error in eBay Python Finding API

Tags: python, yaml

I'm trying to use the `ebay.yaml` file to quickly pass my application keys (specifically my app-id) into the Finding API. However, even though the file is in the same directory as the program, it throws this exception every time I ran the program:

```
    2020-01-22 23:45:34,335 ebaysdk [DEBUG]:execute: verb=findItemsByKeywords data={'keywords': 'buffalo 
    nickel coin', 'itemFilter': [{'name': 'condition', 'value': 'new'}], 'paginationInput': 
    {'entriesPerPage': 10, 'pageNumber': 1}, 'sortOrder': 'PricePlusShippingLowest'}                                                                                           
    Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/utils.py", line 868, in check_header_validity                               
    if not pat.match(value):                                                                                            
    TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                                                                                             
    Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        
    File "FindByKeywords.py", line 21, in <module>                                                                            
    response = api.execute('findItemsByKeywords', request)                                                                
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ebaysdk/connection.py", line 122, in execute                                 
    self.build_request(verb, data, verb_attrs, files)                                                                     
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ebaysdk/connection.py", line 162, in build_request                           
    self.request = request.prepare()                                                                                      
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 259, in prepare                                            
    hooks=self.hooks,                                                                                                     
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 306, in prepare                                            
    self.prepare_headers(headers)                                                                                         
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 440, in prepare_headers                                    
    check_header_validity(header)                                                                                         
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/utils.py", line 872, in check_header_validity                               
    "bytes, not %s" % (name, value, type(value)))                                                                       
    requests.exceptions.InvalidHeader: Value for header {X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME: None} must be of 
    type str or bytes, not <class 'NoneType'>
```

Would anyone know how to stop this from happening? The `ebay.yaml` file contains all of my application keys for all the different APIs including the tokens. The app-id is present within the file which is strange since the exception says that the `APPNAME` is set to `None` when it is present within the file.

For reference, the program, as well as the `ebay.yaml` file, is in a repository `ebay` which is within the `ebaysdk-python` repository I originally got from GitHub. The `ebaysdk-python` is stored in the system root directory of an Ubuntu Linux shell for Windows. 
The program I'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from ebaysdk.finding import Connection as Finding
#import os
#import sys

api = Finding(domain = 'svcs.sandbox.ebay.com',  config_file = 'ebay.yaml', siteid = 'EBAY-US', debug = True)

request = {
    'keywords': 'buffalo nickel coin',
    'itemFilter': [
        {'name': 'condition', 'value': 'new'}
    ],
    'paginationInput': {
        'entriesPerPage': 10,
        'pageNumber': 1
    },
    'sortOrder': 'PricePlusShippingLowest'
}

response = api.execute('findItemsByKeywords', request)
results = open('/mnt/c/Users/iamno/Desktop/SearchResults.txt', 'w')
for item in response.reply.searchResult.item:
    results.write(item.title + "\n")
results.close()
```

If I set `config_file` to `None` and explicitly pass in my app-id into the `appid` parameter, the program works. The `ebay.yaml` is just not being recognized properly.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the default 'ebay.yaml' doesn't have the sanbox domain (svcs.ebay.com is the prod domain)

Just add this in yaml file

```
svcs.sandbox.ebay.com:
    appid: ENTER_YOUR_APPID_HERE
```

Answer (score -1):

Below works for me:

```
from ebaysdk.finding import Connection as Finding

yaml_path='C:/Users/Public/ebay/eBay_API/ebay_1.yaml' #path: yaml file location
api = Finding(config_file=yaml_path, siteid='EBAY-US')
request = {
    'keywords': 'buffalo nickel coin',
    'itemFilter': [
        {'name': 'condition', 'value': 'new'}
    ],
    'paginationInput': {
        'entriesPerPage': 10,
        'pageNumber': 1
    },
    'sortOrder': 'PricePlusShippingLowest'
}
response = api.execute('findItemsByKeywords', request)
print(response.reply.paginationOutput)
```

//
{'pageNumber': '1', 'entriesPerPage': '10', 'totalPages': '982', 'totalEntries': '9813'}

More details connected to eBay API: https://github.com/Brat-Pit/eBay